# How to disable page transitions (for Android devices)

Tags: sencha-touch, extjs, sencha-touch-2

I want to disable page transitions for Android devices but don't know how.

Here is the code of my app.js class:

```
Ext.application({
name: 'app',

models: ['PModel', 'TModel'],
stores: ['PStore', 'TStore'],
controllers: ['HController', 'PController', 'TController'],
views: ['Main'],

launch: function() {
    console.log("app launch");
    Ext.Viewport.add({
         xclass: 'app.view.Main'
    });

    if (Ext.os.is.Android) {
        Ext.Msg.alert("Android detected");
        //TODO: DISABLE PAGE TRANSITIONS
    }
    else{
        Ext.Msg.alert("Another OS detected");
    }
}
});
```

I already made a check to see what OS is running but I can't find how to disable page transitions.

Answer (score 1):

**UPDATE:**

The following function should disable the transitions, so I added this function to my if else statement but it doesn't do anything.

```
Ext.Anim.override({
        disableAnimations:true
    });
```

Now my complete launch function looks like this:

```
    launch: function() {
    if (Ext.os.is.Android) {
        Ext.Msg.alert("Android detected");

        Ext.Anim.override({
            disableAnimations:true
        });
    }
    else{
        Ext.Msg.alert("Another OS detected");
    }

    console.log("app launch");
    Ext.Viewport.add({
         xclass: 'app.view.Main'
    });
}
```